# Could a cylinder spacecraft (similar to an O'Neill cylinder) rotate indefinitely in the vacuum of space?

Tags: rocket-science, centrifugal-force, space

As oppose to a cylinder in two pieces rotating against each other, as in O'Neill's cylinder, what if the cylinder were all one piece and an external thrust, like rockets, set the cylinder in motion, rotating it, would it rotate indefinitely?

Would inhabitants of the cylinder experience artificial gravity indefinitely, or would their movement against the rotation of the cylinder slow it, or would movement with the rotation of the cylinder even it out? Or would neither effect the closed system because they'd be pressing against the cylinder from inside the cylinder? Would friction from the air inside slow the cylinder over time, or would the air turn with the cylinder and artificial gravity?

If any of the above would slow the cylinder, how frequently would the rockets around it have to add more momentum to keep the craft spinning? Would it at least be a number of years?

Comment: The better solution than adding angular momentum with rocket thrusters would be to use counter-rotating masses, so that the net angular momentum is zero. Divide each habitat in multiple sections that are connected by a shaft. That way the stability problem becomes more easily solvable, I believe. I haven't done any calculations, though.

Comment: try here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cylindrical object is not completely rigid—if it's possible for people and other objects to move about inside it—then the only stable axis of rotation will be the one with the greatest moment of inertia. If the length/height of the cylinder is significantly greater than its diameter, then it will prefer to turn end-over-end.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VPfZ_XzisU&t=678s

Comment: I used to have one of O'Neill's popular books. Did he ever solve the control problem in an actual technical paper? One of these structures tumbling would, of course, be catastrophic.